# UISlider making it square not rounded

Tags: swift, uislider

why does it do this? how can i change it? and is there anyway to change the slider so the progress slider is not rounded but square?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfNHo.jpg

I would prefer it to be square, the code is just a normal UI slider implementation. I only edited the

```
override func trackRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, 25)
}
```

to make the bar taller

Answer (score 9):

You can set the minimum and maximum track image.
Just use an image (rectangle without corner radius) with a width of 1px and height of 25px.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006798-CH3-SW21

Sample:

```
slider.setMinimumTrackImage(UIImage(named: "back"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
slider.setMaximumTrackImage(UIImage(named: "back"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

The `back` image is just a blue square image of size 25px.

[image: Slider]

The back Image: (just copy and paste)
[image]

Comment: like create a UIView? and set it as the track image?

Comment: so if you want two toned progress bar like with one side a color and the other side a different color, you just assign a different color to the respective view?

Comment: That gave me this result

http://imgur.com/00LheJb

The min image was set, i would like the max side of the bar to also be a square. 



        let minImage = UIImage(named: "minTrackImage")
        let maxImage = UIImage(named: "maxTrackImage")
        
        scoreSlider.setMinimumTrackImage(minImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        scoreSlider.setMaximumTrackImage(maxImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

Comment: Pleas use the "back" image I provided in my updated answer. This is just what I did to archive an slider without rounded corners.

Answer (score 4):

```
slider.setMaximumTrackImage(UIImage.imageWith(color: .yellow), for: .normal)
slider.setMinimumTrackImage(UIImage.imageWith(color: .cyan), for: .normal)
```

UIImage extension:

```
static func imageWith(color: UIColor, size: CGSize? = nil) -> UIImage? {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size?.width ?? 1, height: size?.height ?? 1)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context?.fill(rect)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Comment: You should provide `UIImage(color:)` method as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple**

```
slider.setMinimumTrackImage(getImageWithColor(color: .blue, size: slider.frame.size), for: .normal)

func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```